# Change the Option height of dropdown

Tags: javascript, css

Is that possible to change height between two options using CSS?

See the illustrative ex. Height between Cash & Credit Card option

[image]

**Note**: I am supporting **Chrome** only

Comment: I think this is not possible using the HTML `<select>` element. You can put empty item if you want, or use custom drop down list using JavaScript.

Comment: It is possible, I've seen it before.

Comment: @user1534664 then go ahead and show us..

Comment: What kind of browser support are you looking for? Webkit, for example, ignores most css on `<option/>`, so you will probably run into trouble there.

Comment: This JS solution might be of use: http://india.assigninfo.com/assignlabs/samples/jALDropDown1_7_9/App_Web/jALDropDown1_7_9.htm

Comment: @PerSalbark: Looking for chrome support only

Comment: @Niks: Chrome uses webkit, so styling is not going to work. NullPointers "tricky way" is probably your best bet. If you're still not happy, there are a million jquery plugins for styled dropdowns available (although I have yet to find a really good one).

Answer (score 16):

Does no one remember [`<optgroup>`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup) anymore? Rarely used, but nonetheless supported in every browser.

```html
<select>
  <optgroup label="Cash">
    <option>Cash</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Other">
    <option>Credit Card</option>
    <option>Credit Note (R)</option>
    <option>Gift Voucher</option>
    <option>Cheque</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: This is not an answer for the question.

Comment: @cuixiping On browsers that don’t allow any styling on `<select>`s and `<option>`s, this is the _only_ available approach. It’s also a semantically richer and more accessible alternative to just increasing the distance between two options.

Answer (score 9):

use a special font(very small) and use `"font-size:200%";`
important: just for option

or

simplest way: option{zoom: 1.5}
done!

[image]

Comment: Worked for me and the team accepted this instead of padding. Used 1.25

Answer (score 7):

Another option is you can change the font size to be larger.

```
.myOption {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Works very well if you are using Font Awesome icons in a drop down list and you want to make them bigger.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
   option{

     padding:5px 0;
   }
```

Example with padding [**Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/swamimayank/Vr6uy/)

```
.dis option{
 padding:5px 0;

 }
```

html

```
<select class="dis">
  <option>1erwer</option>
  <option>2wwerwer</option>
  <option>3werwer</option>
  <option>4werwer</option>
  <option>5wrwer</option>
</select>
```

increasing the space between two options is not possible

[**but there is a tricky way**](http://jsfiddle.net/8WPbk/)

```
<select class="dis">
  <option>1erwer</option>
  <option>2wwerwer</option>
  <option>3werwer</option>
  <option disabled="disabled" ></option> <---trick 
  <option>3werwer</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @Niks please save the fiddle ...your fiddle is empty

Comment: He means the height between two specific options. Such thing is not possible as far as I know.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: then what you trying to explain in above answer?

Comment: @Niks it's not my answer. I commented on the answer. Anyway, +1 for the "tricky way" I was just going to post it myself. Here is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xZK9L) demonstrating this.

Comment: @ShadowWizard i would love to see

Comment: Injecting disabled options is an interesting hack to add gaps, but not great for UX because users would normally expect them to be padding associated with the closest label. The lack of hover and click hotspots in the disabled region are unfortunately going to grate with users.

Answer (score 1):

Not specifically. You cannot control the styling of option lists.  However, you can use something like select2 (https://select2.github.io/examples.html) which creates facade selects that you can style.

Comment: Yes..There are number of custom lib are available now..But was looking solution for html drop down.

Answer (score 1):

Building off [NullPointers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13231430/591285) answer I think I've come up with another great solution. Double up every single option with an empty disabled option, optionally include an extra option at bottom to even out spacing.

```
<select class="dis">
  <option disabled="disabled" ></option> <---trick 
  <option>1erwer</option>
  <option disabled="disabled" ></option> <---trick 
  <option>2wwerwer</option>
  <option disabled="disabled" ></option> <---trick 
  <option>3werwer</option>
  <option disabled="disabled" ></option> <---trick 
  <option>3werwer</option>
  <option disabled="disabled" ></option> <---trick 
</select>
```

Then simply take advantage of css `nth-child` even and odd to individually size the option text and *"spacing"*.

```
option:nth-child(even) {font-size:18px;}
option:nth-child(odd) { font-size:5px;}
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/ep5tg3fq/)

Comment: Ugly to have two option entries, but works great :D

Answer (score -5):

You can always use ul instead of select option

```html
<ul class="dis">
  <li>1erwer</li>
  <li>2erwer</li>
  <li>3erwer</li>
  <li>4erwer</li>
  <li>5erwer</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Nooooo, you can not and should not use something else, then the html-element, that is the onliest and right one for a particular usecase. Why? À list is NOT a form element and is still a readonly list! Think "semanticle", whenever you can! There are people out there, who need screenreaders (just one of many reasons to do so).

Comment: that's totally unrelated, You must use a form element.