# change the height of "option" only with css

Tags: html, css

For example,in the code,"option"is too low,I want to make it higher only with css(no javascript).

```
<select>
    <option>Beijing</option>
    <option>ShangHai</option>
    <option>WuHan</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: What does "too low" mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13231419/change-the-option-height-of-dropdown-css-javascript

Comment: Do you mean the position that the option element is in—as in the placement, the order?

Comment: do you mean the height of the dropdown menu? have you tried a css solution or googled it at least?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to style the option of a html "select"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-a-html-select)

Comment: Maybe my English is poor,i  want  to add the height of the "option ",thanks eveyone

Answer (score 4):

Since `<option>` (and `<select>`) elements are rendered by the browser as a dropdown list,  unfortunately **you cannot style them**, because their style is only controlled by the browser itself.

Answer (score 2):

Change **select > option** to **ul > li** list and you can style as you want it yourself with Cross browser compatibility

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ul` as alternative to style as you want, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8431078/929055).

You can only make options `bold` or change the `font-size`, but it's not possible to change the space of the `option`.

```css
option{font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;}
```

```html
<select>
    <option>Beijing</option>
    <option>ShangHai</option>
    <option>WuHan</option>
  </select>
```

Options are rendered by the OS, not HTML, so the styling is limited.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
option{
     padding:10px 0;
   }
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Vr6uy/507/)

Also you can use the `<optgroup> element` to make it run in Chrome.

**EDIT:-**

Just saw that it is not reliable and cant be addressed perfectly for cross browser solutions.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Styling_HTML_forms) says:

> Some elements simply can't be styled using CSS. These include all
>   advanced user interface widgets such as range, color, or date controls
>   as well as all the dropdown widgets, including , , and elements. The
>   file picker widget is also known not to be stylable at all. The new
>   and elements also fall in this category.

**Alternative other than Javascript:**

If possible then use [Bootstrap's Dropdown.](http://getbootstrap.com/components/)

Comment: @Paulie_D:- I am using IE and it works perfectly fine in that

Comment: I didn't downvote but obviously this solution is not cross-browser...you might want to update your answer to that effect.

Comment: It's not cross browser.

Comment: @Paulie_D:- Yes I also checked in Chrome and other browsers, its not working. Updated my answer(*was checking that only*). Thanks for updating me as well

Comment: @rm4:- Yes  got that. Thanks. Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

`line-height` can be useful
`-webkit-appearance: menulist-button` this one can be used both will work

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerning about the mobile friendliness or the Google's mobile first SEO guidelines where the tappable items must not close to each other, then don't worry, modern mobile web browser will **auto-adjust the item height** for you.

Answer (score -1):

Try This: change the height px to what you wish.

```
.a option { height: 50px; }
```

Comment: what is the object of class "a"?

Comment: Height doesn't work for option of select tag