# How to increase height of Dropdown's select option field?

Tags: css, select, drop-down-menu

I am facing issue in increasing the size of dropdown select option. I have applied styles but its working for background color but not the height.

```html
<select style="width:200px">
  <option value="volvo">
    <div style="height:100px !important ;color:red">Volvo</div>
  </option>
  <option value="saab" style="height:50px;">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel" style="height:50px;">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi" style="height:50px;">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-a-html-select/7208814

Comment: In reference to the comment that @SleekGeek left, you would be able to do this using `HTML` elements like `ul`s, `li`s and javascript.

Comment: You can't put a div in an option

Comment: yes I am doing it using ul li.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [change the height of "option" only with css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29256849/change-the-height-of-option-only-with-css)